# Fragment not opening with if condition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, if-statement

I have an if statement in when i the position 3 is selected that checks a condition of if a particular key has been stored in tinyDB(a form of shared preferences) to open a particular fragment this condition is true(i checked this with the `System.out.println(tiny.getString("userSignedIn");` but the fragment does not open. The condition on position 3 in the code. Than you very much

```
bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Home home = new Home();
                    doTransation(home);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Categories categories = new Categories();
                    doTransation(categories);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    MyDownloads myDownloads = new MyDownloads();
                    doTransation(myDownloads);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (getUserSignedIn.equals("Sign up Successful")){
                        UserSignedInProfile userSignedInProfile = new UserSignedInProfile();
                        doTransation(userSignedInProfile);
                    }else if (getUserSignedIn.equals("Email address or password not correct")){
                        Profile profile = new Profile();
                        doTransation(profile);
                   }
                   break;
                default:
                     Profile profile = new Profile();
                     doTransation(profile);
                     break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is the method for doTransation

```
 private void doTransation(Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parentLayout, fragment);
    moreOptions.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_more);
    moreOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text_changer.setText(R.string.app_name);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I have tried the switch statement but it still does not work

Comment: This could should really be DRY'ed up some - you're repeating yourself a lot here. I would start be rewriting this with a switch statement, and then rewrite it such that you are only calling the first line of each case e.g `MyDownloads myDownloads = new MyDownloads()` - it will then be easier to read your code and see what the problem is. Every line except for the first line of each if block can be extracted such that you write it only once for the whole thing, instead of over and over.

Comment: You could get this whole thing down to a dozen or so lines of code - less code makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Your comparison method getUserSignedIn() is probably not returning what you are expecting. Not sure if you know that or think it's a fragment issue. Can't tell from your question.

Comment: I said in the question that i used System.out.println(getUserSignedIn) to check and it gives me what i expect (04-21 12:50:50.940 1763-1763/? I/System.out:  Sign in Successful)

Comment: Cool, your if check is "Sign up Successful" and your output is "Sign in Successful"

Comment: Ha, thank for that. Changed it to Sign in Successful but it's still the same result

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String [] posts = { "1","2","3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
switch (position){
case 0:
break;
}
```

instead of  if&else

or Change the last option to }else(position == 3){ 
instead of }else if (position == 3){
I think he will succeed

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer is, your if comparison isn't evaluating to try when you expect it to. That is because **getUserSignedIn does not equal the String value "Sign up Successful"**. It is likely a typo, we all make them. If that gets you into your if statement (use a debug log or a breakpoint) then let's start checking your Fragment for issues.

But while we are at it, StackOverflow is for learning, and as you can see from your initial comments your code can use some cleaning:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

        // This is where we can start, you are instantiating a 
        // fragment in your switch statement, so let's start
        // with a fragment variable that we will set in the switch
        // and pass to our method
        Fragment fragment;

        // Now in our switch statement, we simply set our fragment
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new Home();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Categories();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MyDownloads();
                break;
            case 3:
                if (getUserSignedIn.equals("Sign up Successful")){
                    fragment = new UserSignedInProfile();
                    break; // break here so else goes to default
                }
                /* You don't need this since you are just going
                   to default to the Profile fragment
                else if (getUserSignedIn.equals("Email address or password not correct")){
                }
                */
                // Notice no break here, it is in the if condition
            default:
                fragment = new Profile();
        }

        doTransition(profile);  // I think you mean "Transition"(?)
        return true;
    }
});
```

Now if you want to get really fancy, and you understand and can read the code clearly, you can get all ternary up in this bad boy. Ternary operators are where you are basically saying *[Thing] = (if) ? x : y;* but it can be chained into crazy stuff:

```
Fragment fragment = position == 0 ? new Home() :
    positon == 1 ? new Categories() :
    position == 2 ? new MyDownloads() :
    position == 3 && getUserSignedIn.equals("Sign up Successful") ? 
        new UserSignedInProfile() :
    new Profile();

doTransition(fragment);
```

Let's go even further. Are you ever going to use that fragment variable ever again? No? Why create it?

```
doTransition(
    position == 0 ? new Home() :
    position == 1 ? new Categories() :
    position == 2 ? new MyDownloads() :
    position == 3 && getUserSignedIn.equals("Sign up Successful") ? 
        new UserSignedInProfile() :
    new Profile();
);
```